# remove default scope in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I can't seem to remove default scopes from my code. When I run my specs I get a huge stack trace.What am I doing wrong?

```
    module Timer
     included do

        scope :current, -> do
          effective_at(Time.current.to_date)
        end

        default_scope {
           pp "Default Scope Called"
           pp caller
           ee_date(Time.current.to_date)
        }
    end
  end

user.rb
has_many :class_users
include Timer
  def person
    ClassUser.unscoped do
       class_users.current.items
    end
  end
```

Comment: Where is `users` defined? And what is `person` supposed to do?

Comment: grabs the items off the class_users

Comment: The default scope of `User` will not effect `ClassUser` nor `class_users`. `Timer#current` will not be available to `class_users`. Can you show us a *minimal yet complete* version of both User and ClassUser as well as your error?